# Copy PHP website to virtual folder under IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis, web-config, url-rewriting, virtual-directory

I would like to make an existing PHP Website (Apache) run on a virtual folder under IIS 8.5.

With the help of some nice online tools I translated the following .htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to web.config:

```
<rule name="rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^index\.php$"  />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="."  />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php"  />
</rule>
```

This works fine for some URL like `http://www.my_new_website.com/`.

However, my goal is to make this Website run in a **virtual directory** below an ASP.NET web application, e.g. `http://www.my_asp_net_website/php_app/`. Therefore I created a Virtual Directory "php_app" in IIS Manager pointing to directory *C:\ ... \<webroot>\myphpdir* as I would do for an ASP.NET application.

Now I must adapt my web.config; but as I am not very familiar with redirect / rewrite rules and regular expressions, I ask **you**:

**What are the correct rewrite rules in web.config?**

All I tried until now resulted in some missing .css or 404 errors.